# Node.js SQL Server single quote issue with prepared query

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I'm trying to pull data from a SQL Server database using node.js, and passing the data to Google Chatbot.

This is what my SQL Server query looks like

```
INSERT INTO @Return
    SELECT 'You' + '\' + 've assigned ' + CONVERT(varchar(4), COUNT(1)) + ' to yourself'
```

This is the function that sends the data to the Google Chatbot.

```
function GbWebhookFunction(){

    this.sendMessage = async function(strMessage){
        console.log(strMessage);
        fetch(webhookURL, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
            },
            body: "{'text': '" + strMessage + "'}",
        }).then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
        });
    };
};
```

This outputs:

```
You\ve assigned X to yourself
```

I tried to add to my function the code below but that did not work.

```
strMessage = strMessage.replace("\", "'");
```

I removed one `\` from my SQL query but that outputted:

```
Youe assigned X to yourself
```

[Output when I remove `\` from the SQL query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EMRN.png)

Any ideas on how I can replace the `\` with a single quote?

Comment: I suggest you try and implement native escape methods. For example, this in SQL is how you embed a quote: `SELECT 'You''ve assigned'`. Now you have exactly the string you want from SQL, you need to work out how to preserve that in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

In your query you forgot to add the single quote. The query should most likely be

```sql
INSERT INTO @Return
    SELECT 'You\'ve assigned ' + CONVERT(varchar(4), COUNT(1)) + ' to yourself'
```

### Edit

Based on some provided errors I would instead suggest using the double single quotes. Which means the SQL query should be as followed:

```sql
INSERT INTO @Return
    SELECT 'You''ve assigned ' + CONVERT(varchar(4), COUNT(1)) + ' to yourself'
```

Comment: The highlighting used by stack overflow doesn't really like escapes, however this is valid.

Comment: When I paste that into SSMS and run it I get _Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'assigned'.
Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ''._

Comment: I made an edit. Apparently mariadb handles escapes differently from mysql

Comment: Since this is for SQL Server, I'm not sure what relevance mariadb and mysql has.

Comment: The latest edit was adjusted to by MySQL compatible, I initially just assumed that mariadb inherited the quote escaping from MySQL

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. The tag in the question is sql-server. Not mariadb or mysql.